# Record with Group by clause on created_at is 9 but it gives the total instead which is 12 without group by in laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I have 3 tables, Users, Tasks, TasksSession.

what I am trying to find is total session conducted and total days the user was involved in that task based on `created_at` group by statement.

```php
User::with(['Task','TotalSessionsGroupByDate'])
->withCount(['TotalSessions','TotalSessionsGroupByDate'])
->whereId(2)
->first(),
```

With the above `total_sessions_group_by_date_count = 12` and `total_sessions_group_by_date_count = 9 records in an array`.

function code for the `TotalSessionsGroupByDate` is as follows

```php
public function TotalSessionsGroupByDate()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TaskSession::class)->groupBy('created_at');
}
```

I have the total number of the session conducted / attendance but how to get the total number of days irrelevant to sessions. as per the example, `total_sessions_group_by_date_count` should be `9` and not `12` total_sessions_group_by_date_count.

---

the only solution that I was able to find as of now, able to come up is as below:

```php
$user = User::with(['TaskIssues','TotalSessionsGroupByDate'])
->withCount(['TotalSessions'])
->whereId(16)
->first();

$user->TotalSessionsGroupByDate = $user->TotalSessionsGroupByDate->count();
```

any better way to do the same in model?

Comment: Do you want SQL or something else?

Comment: I guess you need to debug in smaller chunks to see why this problem occurs.

Comment: @jarth  I have provided the fix which I was able to figure out. it's not ideal but works. but with that code, if you are able to understand what I want to do and provide me with a solution on the same, please let me know.

Comment: @senty same thing for you as above comment